# How to route and network Vagrant VM instances?

Tags: vagrant, puphpet

I have recently started using Vagrant instead of MAMP for some small projects (mainly WordPress) However, decided to try my hand at React and am wondering wether it is possible to use the two together?

At the moment I have a Vagrant setup created via PuPHPet which works fine and runs a local server on a VM which I can access via a URL - local.gethandle.com. I also downloaded a React starter kit as a starting point from a Facebook github page and it requires you to run a server e.g. node server.js which also works and I can access from a separate URL - http://localhost:3000/. But cant seem to access my React application via my Vagrant URL.

How do I combine the two? If at all possible.

Comment: This isnt a question about React, or a node server, it is only related to how to route and network Vagrant VM instances, you might get better answers if it is renamed.

Answer (score 0):

Oki doki, 
caveat: I've not looked at what kind of VM is provisioned via PuPHPet..

First you'll need to vagrant ssh into your vagrant vm and download the react tools **into your vagrant vm**
https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/up.html

Second you'll then want to edit your Vagrant file that should be in the directory on your machine where your vagrant settings are, then have a look and add some networking config 
https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/networking.html

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 4567
# guest is your machine, host is your vagrant vm
# e.g config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add the port to your firewall:

[image]